# Is the purpose of a distributed Bragg reflector to only allow specific wavelengths in the quantum well?

Tags: optics, quantum-optics

Is the actual useful function of the dielectric mirrors in a distributed Bragg reflector the stopband they create, so that only specific frequencies will make into the quantum well in the middle?

Or is it some crazy advanced stuff about trapping light on either side of the quantum well?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: Making a high-Q cavity is pretty useful, no?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're thinking of a configuration where you have some form of micropillar that contains a quantum well surrounded on either side by a Bragg reflector, i.e. something like this:

> [image]
>
> [Image source](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4733726)

If that's the case, then the purpose of the Bragg reflectors is simply to reflect the light back and forth, so that a high-quality cavity is formed within the dielectric stack and without needing fancier construction techniques (which would be impossible to apply at those scales).

If that's not what you meant, then you need to provide a whole lot more context in your question.

Comment: Why in the image it seems that light Is emitted horizontally? This seems a vertical cavity micropillar. I thought that emission were on the vertical axis